# pusher pass parameter in laravel broadcastAs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

hi i have this js code

```
    var pusher = new Pusher('my pusher key', {
        cluster: 'ap2'
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

    channel.bind('my-event', function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

and this is my laravel code

```
protected $pos_invoice;
public function __construct($pos_invoice)
{
    $this->pos_invoice = $pos_invoice;
}
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('my-channel');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'my-event';
}
```

and this is the call code

```
return event( new \App\Events\New_pos_online_order_event('aa'));
```

now the code

```
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

always return [] on console so i tried this

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'my-event.'.$this->pos_invoice;
}
```

and this

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('my-channel'.'asdfasdf');
}
```

when i change anything on

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return 'my-channel';
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'my-event';
}
```

the code not working and not returning anything on console
so how can i pass parameter on pusher and laravel with js
thanks ..

Comment: For us to debug what is actually going wrong, we need more than "the code not working and not returning anything on console so how can i pass parameter on pusher and laravel with js thanks .."

Comment: channel.bind('my-event', function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });

Look after this piece of code event name on laravel you have making dynamic & you have to bind with the same even name on frontend to ... to debug this . we have look after your code . ping me on twitter @Sai_Saravana_ we can connect remotely to debug this iisue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function [broadcastWith](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#broadcast-data)

```
**
 * Get the data to broadcast.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastWith()
{
    return ['pos_invoice' => $this->pos_invoice];
}
```

You will receive the array in the data of the bind function